# Bootstrap Form Validation or Required not working on Ajax submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a form with bootstrap UI. i want to make my input, select option fields required. But my code not working.

Here following markup and code details on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/g28vvw77/

Is that possible by writing a function here,

```
 $('#paynow').click(function(){

}
```

I tried to used validator.js but it does not work, may be for ajax issue. Anyone can review my code and give solution to make field validation or just required warning.

I just want to implement this type of feature, http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/

Comment: have you try <input required>

Comment: Yes i tried.. it does not work.. http://s5.postimg.org/y7dv14faf/screenshot_104.png

Comment: change event to **$(".form-horizontal").submit(function(){ });**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g28vvw77/7/ 

your code is worked with 1 button submit added

Comment: but i need to active it on pay now button..

Comment: coz on that submit button there i have a click function to send email and then process to paypal order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this syntax to validate your form

```
     $("#f").validate({
                rules: {
                    field01: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    field02:{
                        required: true,
                    },
                    field03: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    field04: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    field05: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                     form.submit();
                 }
      });
```

here is `f` is your form id and `field0*` will be the name of your input fields that you want to be required.

Comment: Great!!!! It works and actually i was looking for that code... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would add the `required` tag to your input and select elements that are actually required.
Your code looks like it's processing correctly, however you aren't validating anything with your JS or with HTML5.

**EDIT:**
You have a rogue `</form>` tag. It's closing the form before the buttons are introduced.
If you remove line 226 of your JSFiddle example, it should fix the problem.

Comment: I tired with required but it did not work.. :( 
still there, have 
<input name="client_company_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="client_company_name" placeholder="Company Name" required>

 can you show me updated jsfiddle plz

i am trying to implement that http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/ on my jsfiddle

Comment: The problem is caused by a `</form>` tag before the Pay Now button. Which means the buttons are no longer attached to that form. It's just a couple of lines below the "50 Breedings" select option. Works fine once that's fixed.

Comment: Yes... your point is correct but my form not processing when i am adding only 1 <form> tag then my form not processing... so i think there need to use js click function for making fields required

Comment: I'm just curios, are you using a server to test html required validation? I think you might need a server like in the following example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required But with jQuery you can test the input without a server.

Comment: Yes.. that is my live form.. 
https://freshplusdirect.com/order/
and when i am changing the button position that time required message showing by HTML5 but form it goes to next step. coz i have jquery click function in that submit button